# How to display current user details from database in separate page in php

Tags: php

Here is my index.php:

```
<?php
    define('INCLUDE_CHECK',1);
    require "config.php";
    require "functions.php";
    require "data.php";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Creating a Facebook-like Registration Form with jQuery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div-regForm">
<div class="form-title">Sign Up</div>
<div class="form-sub-title">It's free and anyone can join</div>
<form id="regForm" action="submit.php" method="post">
<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="fname">First Name:</label></td>
    <td><div class="input-container"><input name="fname" id="fname" type="text" /></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="lname">Last Name:</label></td>
    <td><div class="input-container"><input name="lname" id="lname" type="text" /></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="email">Your Email:</label></td>
    <td><div class="input-container"><input name="email" id="email" type="text" /></div></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="pass">New Password:</label></td>
    <td><div class="input-container"><input name="pass" id="pass" type="password" /></div></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><label for="pass">Phone Number:</label></td>
    <td><div class="input-container"><input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" /></div></td>
  </tr>
    <td><label for="sex-select">I am:</label></td>
    <td>
    <div class="input-container">
    <select name="sex_select" id="sex-select">
    <option value="0">Select Sex:</option>
    <option value="1">Female</option>
    <option value="2">Male</option>
    </select>
    </div>   
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Birthday:</label></td>
    <td>
    <div class="input-container">
    <select name="month"><option value="0">Month:</option><?=generate_options(1,12)?></select>
    <select name="day"><option value="0">Day:</option><?=generate_options(1,31)?></select>
    <select name="year"><option value="0">Year:</option><?=generate_options(date('Y'),1900)?></select>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input type="submit" class="greenButton" value="Sign Up" /><img id="loading" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="working.." />
</td>
  </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
<div id="error">
&nbsp;
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

data.php:

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if(! $conn )
    {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $sql = 'SELECT fname, lname, email FROM crop';

    mysql_select_db('crop');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if($result){ $sql = "SELECT fname, lname, email FROM crop where id='$id'"; $retval = mysql_query( $sql); if(! $retval ) { die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error()); } while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { echo "First Name :{$row['fname']} <br> ". "Last Name : {$row['lname']} <br> ". "Email Address : {$row['email']} <br> ". "--------------------------------<br>"; } }
       echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
    mysql_close($conn);
    ?>
```

I have created register form using php and jquery and some functions are used.

Now i need, after registered, that current user details display in separate page.

Now i got, nothing to displayed, it shows just data fetched successfully.

Please help me to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: actually its quite straightforward, after the registration, you could save the last inserted id to the session (which is the user id), and then from that separate file, read the session to get the id then use that id to the select query of the separate file

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 wow, i've seen your discussion on that other post, its quite a ton lol. anyway thats pretty much it, same as your answer, using session, but instead just save the id, then, use that to query on that other php page

Comment: Still i am changing code dr.

Comment: this is an official site know, so if u want come to hangouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
       include 'config.php';
        error_reporting(E_ERROR);
        session_start();
        $fname=$_POST['fname'];
        $lname=$_POST['lname'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $pass=$_POST['pass'];
        $phone=$_POST['phone'];
        $sex_select=$_POST['sex_select'];
        $month=$_POST['month'];
        $day=$_POST['day'];
        $year=$_POST['year'];

        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO crop(fname, lname, email, pass, phone,`sex_select`, month,day,year)  
    VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$pass','$phone','$sex_select', '$month','$day','$year')");
    if(mysql_affected_rows()>1)
        {

        //it will redeirect you to. your any file. 
        //you can give any file name here. 
           $_SESSION['fname']=$fname;//you are adding value to the session
         $_SESSION['lanme']=$lname; //you are adding value to the session
    //Do this for rest of your value
    header('Location:Your_File_name.php');
        }



    if (!$result) {
        die(msg(0,"wrong query"));
    }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check some basic `PHP` and `MySql` examples on how to insert and retrieve data.

http://w3epic.com/php-mysql-login-system-a-super-simple-tutorial/

http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-a-sign-up-form-registration-with-php-and-mysql/28675

Comment: I am asking, exact current user details need to display.

Comment: Can you successfully insert row in mysql at register event? If you can, parhaps you should google like "mysql query and show data using php". A simple tutorial at - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_select_php.htm
Remember, no one's going write you full code.

Comment: Or if you want you can use PHP SESSION. using session you can store current user info - like user id and then using that id show his info.